# How is it possible for someone to suffer repeated bouts of flu?

Tags: immune-system, influenza

About a month and a half ago I caught flu... recovered fairly quickly (2 days), and then 1 week later I caught another one, again, recovered even faster (just 1 day, a good night sleep) and a week ago I caught another one, this time it took me 2 days to combat it off.

I have read about it that there are only 2 strands of influenza, it is possible to get both strands, within relatively short time, but it is impossible to get the same strand within a limited time frame.

Yet here I was, catching flu again and again. What was going on? Did I catch flu of the same strand, only mutated?

Comment: It wasn't the flu.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things going on here.

First off, there are many, many strands of the flu. [According to the CDC](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12100836):

> Influenza A viruses are divided into subtypes based on two proteins on
>   the surface of the virus: the hemagglutinin (H) and the neuraminidase
>   (N). There are 18 different hemagglutinin subtypes and 11 different
>   neuraminidase subtypes. (H1 through H18 and N1 through N11
>   respectively.)
>
> Influenza A viruses can be further broken down into different strains.
>   Current subtypes of influenza A viruses found in people are influenza
>   A (H1N1) and influenza A (H3N2) viruses. In the spring of 2009, a new
>   influenza A (H1N1) virus (CDC 2009 H1N1 Flu website) emerged to cause
>   illness in people. This virus was very different from the human
>   influenza A (H1N1) viruses circulating at that time. The new virus
>   caused the first influenza pandemic in more than 40 years. That virus
>   (often called “2009 H1N1”) has now replaced the H1N1 virus that was
>   previously circulating in humans.
>
> Influenza B viruses are not divided into subtypes, but can be further
>   broken down into lineages and strains. Currently circulating influenza
>   B viruses belong to one of two lineages: B/Yamagata and B/Victoria.

So while there are only a few strains of Type A flu, there are many strains of Type B.

[More importantly, **the flu is very different from a cold**](https://www.cdc.gov/flu/takingcare.htm). Typically it takes at least a week to recover from the flu, with symptoms including fever, muscle aches, and URI symptoms. It's pretty unusual for someone to recover from the flu in just 2 days-- if you got better that quickly, you probably just had a cold.